# 'Email you received last week was/is spam'

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense

I'm confused about these two sentences:

1. email you received last week was spam
2. email you received last week is spam

Which one is correct?

Comment: Why do you think one of them is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible. The use of "was" is an example of backshifting in a context other than reported speech.

In reported speech it is common to "backshift"

> John said, "I am a tennis player".
> John said that he was a tennis player.

You back shift "am" to "was".  In this case, it is optional if you know that John is still a tennis player.

In the same way, when reporting the receipt of a spam email you may backshift to "... was spam".  But it is optional if you know that it is still spam. So "... is spam" is also possible.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following sentences are correct:

> 1. The email you received last week was spam.

> 2. The email you received last week is spam.

In both sentences, "received" must be in the past tense, but "is/was" can be in past or present.

(1) is most common because it all happened in the past.

You might say (2) if you didn't know last week whether the email was spam, but now you know it is.